# VSCode Run Code will not run code to Output window

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, settings

When I click the play button, I get this in the output window:
[Output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTmt1.png)

I am running a python file that imports numpy in a conda virtual environment and have installed numpy via the terminal with "conda install numpy".

If I click the dropdown menu at the play button and select "Run Python File" it successfully runs and outputs to the terminal.

I would like to be able to just "Run Code" and get results in the Output window like everyone else. I feel like this must be an issue with my JSON settings...
[JSON setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJB2Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Change the code-runner executorMap settings in the User JSON file.

"code-runner.executorMap": {
"python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"
}

Code runs in the output window as expected now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).